# How to prevent a textbox from entering a character more than once

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress

I don't want the textbox to let the user to enter letters and the following characters '-' ,'.' more than once, but allow them to press the 'Enter' Key. I'm using the below code:

```
 private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-')
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
                MessageBox.Show("X Origin Can Only Accepts Numbers, a Point '.' and a minus '-'", "ATTENTION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) ?

Comment: MaskedTextBox can Prevent you from entering numbers or letters or symbols, I want to enter symbols but only allow the user to enter the symbols allowed once.

Comment: If you need general solution, then you can check already entered text (`textBox3.Text`) and if it contains something what should be only entered once, then prevent it. However, looking at what you are doing, are you sure `MessageBox` is a great thing to show in the middle of user input? What if user what to *edit* text and find out he is not able to insert e.g. `-` because there is already `-` which he has to delete first? If I'd expect from user formatted input, then I'd use `MaskedTextBox`, otherwise - will check his input **after** pressing confirmation button.

Comment: This code doesn't allow you to enter anything else than numbers and the couple of symbols mentioned in line 2. However when a forbidden character is entered, a message box pops up telling them why that character hasn't been entered in the messagebox...Anyway I'm not having problems with that, I'm having problems with preventing users from entering the above symbols more than once...Do you know the answer?

Comment: Be careful about key press... There are ways to enter data in text field without "key press" being fired.  Like draging text using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion from commenter Sinatr that it would be better to display the validation result in some other way. That said, taking your question literally – i.e. to prevent the user from entering even permitted characters more than once – one implementation might look something like this:

```
private readonly HashSet<char> _enteredChars = new HashSet<char>();

private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-') &&
        _enteredChars.Add(e.KeyChar))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
        MessageBox.Show("X Origin Can Only Accepts Numbers, a Point '.' and a minus '-'", "ATTENTION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

This uses a `HashSet<char>` to store each character already entered. If a key is pressed and the character is already in the set (i.e. `Add()` returns `false`), the code will jump to the same error handling used for invalid characters.

You can of course modify the above example to handle the "already entered" scenario differently from the "invalid character", i.e. to present a different error message, or even to just ignore those key presses.

Also note that the set is only ever added to here. You would want to track the removal of characters from the field, removing them from the `HashSet<char>` at the same time. You could simplify this aspect by simply examining the text field directly for each key press instead of using the `HashSet<char>`. That is:

```
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    if ((char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-') &&
        !textBox.Text.Contains(e.KeyChar))
```

For very long text entries, this could be a bit slower than the `HashSet<char>` based approach. But otherwise I doubt you'd notice a difference, and for very short text entries this could even be faster.

The advantage of using the `textBox.Text` property directly is that it's simpler; you don't have to worry about keeping anything in sync with the data entered so far, as you're always just checking that data directly.